# In Aurelia, can I bind a function from my containing view-model to be called by my custom element?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have a custom element which will take user input, and on [save] button click, I want to pass information to the parent view-model so I can send it to the server and move to the next section.  I'm going to simplify this for example's sake:

`my-element.js`:

```
import { customElement, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('my-element')
@bindable('save')
export class MyElement { }
```

`my-element.html`:

```
<template>
    <button click.delegate="save()">Click this</button>
</template>
```

`parent-view-model.js`:

```
export class ParentViewModel {
  parentProperty = 7;
  parentMethod() {
    console.log(`parent property: ${this.parentProperty}`);
  }
}
```

`parent-view-model.html`:

```
<template>
    <require from="./my-element"></require>
    <div class="content-panel">
        <my-element save.bind="parentMethod"></my-element>
    </div>
</template>
```

For a demo, see (app.js and app.html represent parent-view-model.js and parent-view-model.html):

https://gist.run/?id=96b203e9ca03b62dfb202626c2202989

It works!  Kind of.  Unfortunately, `this` seems to be bound to `my-element` instead of `parent-view-model`, so in this example, what is printed to console is: `parent property: undefined`.  That will not work.

I know I can utilize the EventAggregator to facilitate some communication between the custom element and the view-model, but if I can help it I'd like to avoid the added complexity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two options for this. You could handle this using Custom Events, or you can do it using the `call` binding that Anj mentioned in his answer. Which one you use depends on your actual use case.

If you want the custom element to be able to call a method on your parent VM and pass data *out* of the custom element, then you should use a Custom Event as shown in this gist: https://gist.run/?id=ec8b3b11f4aa4232455605e2ce62872c:

*app.html:*

```
<template>
    <require from="./my-element"></require>
    <div class="content-panel">
        <my-element save.delegate="parentMethod($event)"></my-element>
    </div>

    parentProperty = '${parentProperty}'
</template>
```

*app.js:*

```
export class App {
  parentProperty = 7;
  parentMethod($event) {
    this.parentProperty = $event.detail;
  }
}
```

*my-element.html:*

```
<template>
    <input type="text" value.bind="eventDetailValue" />
    <button click.delegate="save()">Click this</button>
</template>
```

*my-element.js:*

```
import { inject, customElement, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('my-element')
@inject(Element)
export class MyElement {
  eventDetailValue = 'Hello';

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  save() {
    var event = new CustomEvent('save', { 
      detail: this.eventDetailValue,
      bubbles: true
    });

    this.element.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

You would basically attach any data you need to pass on the `detail` property of the Custom Event. In the event binding declaration, you would add `$event` as a parameter to the function and then check the `detail` property of $event in your event handler (you could also just pass `$event.detail` if you wanted).

If you want the custom element to be able to call a method on your parent VM and have data passed in from the parent VM (or from another custom element or something), then you should use the `call` binding. You can specify arguments that will be passed to the method by specifying them in the binding declaration (`foo.call="myMethod(myProperty)"`. These arguments come from the VM context where the binding is being declared, not from the Custom Element's VM).

Answer (score 10):

I was able to solve this after trolling through the aurelia docs hub for a bit.  I don't know all the nuances that may be involved, but for this simple example, I was able to fix it by doing the following simple change:

In parent-view-model.html (or app.html in the gist-run example), change `save.bind="parentMethod"` to `save.call="parentMethod()"`

I am still unsure how to pass data from the custom element into the parent view-model's method, however.

[Here is the documentation from aurelia website.](http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#function-references)

Comment: Updated link for the comment from @rodu: http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#function-references

Answer (score 0):

To pass parametrized functions to custom child components write the following (according to documentation http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#function-references).

*Parent ViewModel*

```js
private _generate(myParam:string) {
    return myParam + " world";
}
```

*Parent View*

```html
<custom-comp generator.call="_generate(myParam)"></custom-comp>
```

*Child View*

```html
<template bindable="generator">
${generator({myParam:"hello"})}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been updated for [aurelia v2](https://docs.aurelia.io/developer-guides/migrating-to-aurelia-2#call-binding-some-prop.call-...):

The call binding no longer assigns properties of the first argument pass to the call to the calling override context. This is unreasonably dynamic and could result in hard-to-understand templates.
In Aurelia 1, you would have used call bindings like this:

```
export class MyElement {
  onChange;

  onInternalButtonClick() {
    this.onChange({ value: this.value });
  }
}

<my-element on-change.call="propertyChanged(value)">
```

In Aurelia 2, the property name is now on the $event property passed to the callback. It's a minor change, but you now do this instead:

```
<my-element on-change.call="propertyChanged($event.value)">
```